# DELETE method returns "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." with IIS

Tags: asp.net, laravel, iis, web-config

I deployed my laravel 10 project on a windows IIS server
all types of requests are working correctrly,
the ploblem here only with DELETE method returns
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
the problem is only happining with DELETE method
tried to add delete method to request filtering

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
        <add origin="*" />
        <add origin="https://*.easy-resume.site"
             allowCredentials="false"
             maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                <add header="Content-Type" />
                <add header="Authorization" />
                <add header="Accept" />
                <!-- Add any other headers you want to allow -->
            </allowHeaders>
            <allowMethods>
                <add method="GET" />
                <add method="POST" />
                <add method="PUT" />
                <add method="DELETE" />
                <!-- Add any other methods you want to allow -->
            </allowMethods>
            <exposeHeaders>
                <add header="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
                <!-- Add any other headers you want to expose -->
            </exposeHeaders>
        </add>
        <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
    </cors>
<httpProtocol>  
    <customHeaders>  
    </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>  
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNsHf.png)
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7CXa.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some code that can help us investigate the issue. Share the route, controller method, and the DELETE request you're making. It's obviously that you are missing your auth credentials for the endpoint, but we can try to guide you a bit, if you update your question with some code.

Comment: could you please share the detailed error message snapshot? check iis logs which sub status code it is showing. try enabling directory browsing in iis.

Comment: I added web.config code, and two images, you can check, and in the ISS request filtering I added verb DELETE as allowed, but nothing changed.   thanks for your help.

Comment: IIS logs    `2024-01-17 00:04:56 136.243.120.99 DELETE /api/v1/logout - 443 - 41.42.81.112 HTTP/2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:121.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/121.0 https://dashboard.easy-resume.site/ easy-resume.site 403 0 0 1233 551 139`

Comment: @mostafaElsaprout try adding this code "customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>" if issue still persist check the console logs

Comment: Nothing worked for me, I tried everything and in the end, I had to reinstall the Windows server and do all the work again now all is good.  thanks for your help.